# Failure in the use of FullSimplify

Tags: evaluation, simplifying-expressions, syntax

My question is about an apparent failure of the function "FullSimplify" to simplify an easy algebraic expression.

This is the expression that I ask Mathematica to evaluate:

```
FullSimplify[Re[a^(I*b)] - Re[a^(-I*b)], Element[a, Reals] && a > 0 && Element[b, Reals]]
```

This should give the result 0. Instead Mathematica only restates my expression:

```
Re[a^(-I b) (-1 + a^(2 I b))]
```

Replacing a and b by actual numbers solves the problem.

What could be the cause of it? How to effectively use FullSimplify (and Simplify, Expand, Integrate and so...) with assumptions?

I read that the order of variables could play a role here, but I couldn't wrap my head around it.

I tried to check for similar problems on the website as well, but I couldn't find any answer that could explain this phenomenon.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Have you tried `ComplexExpand[]`?

Comment: It looks like you need to put `ComplexExpand` under `Re[]` : `FullSimplify[Re[(a^(I*b) - a^(-I*b)) // ComplexExpand], 
 Element[a, Reals] && a > 0 && Element[b, Reals]]`

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I don't have my Mathematica copy right here but I'm gonna try it tomorrow!

Comment: It works! :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by "Guess who it is" and "BlacKow", the solution is to use the function `ComplexExpand[]`, or to add `ComplexExpand` under `Re[]`.